# Creating an .ics calendar subscription service with wordpress

Tags: uploads, filesystem

At the moment I just have a static page with a link that when clicked will download all the events I have on my .ics file to a phone's calendar. Ideally what I would like is for people to be able to subscribe to my calendar so the events update automatically if they change.

To do this I need to allow people to subscribe to the calendar using the URL of the file rather than clicking on a link. Is there a way to allow visitors to my WordPress site to access www.mydomain.com/calendar.ics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Went into the media library and found the URL of the file in there and now it works.